# “each of us” vs “both of us”

Tags: meaning, expressions, determiners

A guy said that he will give them 20 bucks if they wash his car. So they asked him that question to make it clear. But I am confused by their reply:

> **Is that 20 bucks for each of us or both of us?**

The guy said "Both."

Then how much are they going to get?
Total 20 bucks or 40 bucks?

Comment: If both phrases are present (as they are in your example), you're right. Otherwise, "for both of us" on its own may be ambiguous in common usage.

Comment: It would be clearer to say: "Is that 20 bucks for each of us or 20 bucks in total?"

Comment: Or: "Is that 20 bucks for each of us or 20 bucks between us?"

Comment: And ***now*** we know why the OP's confused. Well who wouldn't be? What a wonderful devious crafty answer by the car owner. Where did the scene take place? Which state?

Comment: If we say "Both my friends got a book" this means there are two books. "They both got a book" = two books. "Both of them got a twenty-dollar bill" = total $40

Comment: @Mari-Lou A It took place in Modern Family Season 3 Episode 16. Thank you. Now I am clear.

Comment: Arggggghhhhhh! Why didn't you say so!

Comment: But "He gave us a twenty-dollar bill" = total $20. He gave us one bill of twenty dollars. The car owner's reply  is deliberately ambiguous.

Comment: Well.. I didn't think it was the important fact to tell.. sorry about that.

Comment: But it's the car owner's reply "both" which is wonderfully crafty and sneaky. Does he mean "both" the solutions, or just the twenty dollars for the job (cleaning the car) and for them to divide.

Answer (score 2):

"Each" is a determiner and is used for single things: "Each of you need to make a plan for next week's meeting." or "Each employee will receive a bonus based on their performance."

"Both" is also a determiner but is used for things considered together as in a group, whole or more commonly, two items or people.  "Both Jack and Jill work in accounting on Friday."  or "Both of my sisters live in New York."

"Both" and "Each" can be followed by "of" as in the above examples

In your sentence, "Is that $20 for each of us or both of us?" what the speaker wants to know is if he or she will have to share twenty dollars with the other person (each will receive $10) or if they will each get $20.  On paper, the use of the word "that" is confusing because it is either talking about "that" $20 bill or "that" as in an agreement that they have.  During the conversation, it would have been clear because of the context and also follow up: "That's 20 for each of you." or "That's 20 for both of you to split."

Answer (score 0):

To the question: Is that $20 dollars for each of us or for both of us?

The simple answer without all the useless rhetoric here, is: $20 dollars for the both of you = $10 dollars apiece. The key word here being *each*. Each would imply $20 dollars apiece whereas *both* [meaning total here] implies that the $20 dollars is to be split [shared] between the two.

Eons later I know--but I hope it helps!